# Google maps url to goole maps sdk

Tags: swift, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

Can I use shared location or route url via google maps in sdk. For example, can I open the route url I created on google maps in my own application? example link: https://goo.gl/maps/n15Bt48Bu5nWap8B8

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use roads API

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/roads/snap

The Roads API takes up to 100 GPS points collected along a route, and returns a similar set of data, with the points snapped to the most likely roads the vehicle was traveling along. Optionally, you can request that the points be interpolated, resulting in a path that smoothly follows the geometry of the road.